# Not passing correct value to get_post_ancestors?

Tags: variables

I've got a custom plugin that creates a menu in the sidebar.

I need to be able to specify that, if a particular custom post type is current, the menu displays as if it were on a specific page (so that it looks as if the custom post is actually a child of the specified page.)

Here's my code:

```
            global $wp-query;

            $thisid = $wp_query->post->ID;

            $type = get_post_type( $thisid );

            if($type == 'ia_dir'){
                $thisid = '19';
                }

            $thispost = get_post($thisid);
                if (!$thispost->post_parent) {

                    // if top-level, display only the subpages of this top level page
                    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$thisid."&echo=0&depth=1");
                    if($children) { // Get post ID to display section title only if this top level page has children
                        $top_page = $thisid;
                    }

                }else{ // if not, display the siblings of all ancestors and the siblings and children of the current post

                    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($thisid);
                        // now you can get the ID of the top ancestor of this page;  wp is putting the ids DESC, thats why the top level ID is the last one, and that's why we use "end"
                        $top_page = end($ancestors);
                        //initialize pagelist variable to hold list of pages to include
                        $pagelist = "";

                        //add the immediate children (no grandchildren) of each page in this page's ancestory to the list
                        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
                            $pageset = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_type=page&post_parent='.$ancestor);
                            foreach ($pageset as $apage) {
                                $pagelist = $pagelist.$apage->ID.",";
                                }
                            }

                        //add any children of the current page to the list
                        $pageset = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_type=page&post_parent='.$thisid);
                        foreach ($pageset as $apage) {
                            $pagelist = $pagelist.$apage->ID.",";
                            }

                        //get the list of pages, including only those in our page list
                        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order&include='.$pagelist);

                    }
```

The Issue I'm having is in the "else" section of the "post parent" check. If the post is not specified as "ia_dir" post type, then everything works well, I can get the ancestors and create the list.

If it *is* an "ia_dir" post, however, (i.e., the id is passed manually to $thisid and then to the get_post_ancestors), then I get an empty $ancestors array. I've tried a bunch of different page ids in the type check, and nothing works. I can even specify a page id that I know works fine if I actually visit that page, but when I go to an "ia_dir" post and pass that page id manually, the array is empty.

This is really odd. The only thing I'm doing differently is passing a specific manual page id number to $thisid. Why is this not working?

Edit:

The else statement is functioning either way - I get the $ancestors array always. If I visit post 19 (which is a page), I get the listing because the $ancestors array is populated. However, if I visit an 'ia_dir' post, I get an empty $ancestors array, as if I did not pass '19' to get post ancestors.

So I assume I'm passing an incorrect value to get_post_ancestors. But after poring over the WP codex, I can't figure out why passing the post number, either by a string or as as an integer, won't work for me.

Comment: Are you able to print anything in the `else` statement or is it just that `$thisid` isn't being recognized and therefore not executing `get_post_ancestors()`?

Comment: Please change the title: It should reflect the specific problem you have.

Comment: @developdaly - As I mentioned, the whole thing works fine if I the post type is not 'ia_dir', and thus $thisid is not set by that if statement. So it appears that I'm not passing a valid format to get_post_ancestors - but I know absolutely that this post id is valid (the whole think works if I actually visit post 19, for example, but if I visit an 'ia_dir' post so that post 19 is manually passed to get_post_ancestors, the $ancestors array is empty. It exists, and the whole if statement works otherwise, but the array is empty.)

Comment: @toscho - sorry, I really didn't know what to put there because I wasn't sure what the problem was. I think it might have to do with an incorrect value being passed, but I'm still not certain. Is this better?

Comment: Yeah, better. I wasn't sure too; that's why I asked you to do it. :) When you write a title always think: _How would I search for this problem?_

Comment: Heh! That's why I was generic - I didn't want to box myself in where I didn't belong :) I do take your point, though, and generally try to be as specific as I can in forums. I know how unhelpful generic titles are. Thanks for keeping me honest :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

`$thisid` can be passed as an array, as [`get_post_anscestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors).

So try `$ancestors = get_post_ancestors( array( $thisid ) );`

I misread; it does accept strings, but maybe give an array a shot.

Comment: Interesting. It does not say that at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors).

Also, when $thisid comes from the post (instead of being manually set), it isn't an array. However, I'll try this out.